# Programatically retrieve the updated og:image of a page in an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

There seem to be many pages where the the og:image does not change as I keep browsing from one page to another. The og:image always points to the first (landing) page. This is true of youtube videos, for instance. Of course, reloading the page provides the correct og:image

I am wondering if there is a way, within a custom extension on Chrome and Safari, to force refresh the og:image data without affecting user experience?

Comment: Not sure I understand. I want to ideally have some generic logic in my extension to retrieve the og:image. If the og:image does not update as the user browses, I was wondering if there was a way to force refresh the og:image.

Comment: Would you know how I would do it for youtube - I do realize I can use the og:image pattern and use the appropriate video id, but is there a way to actually refresh the og:image value on the page itself?

Comment: Appreciate your help. If you want to put in the answer below I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically updated sites (aka AJAX sites) change only a portion of the page with the new content on intra-site navigation. The meta information in `head` element like og:image isn't updated usually.

A universal workaround for any site with AJAX navigation would be to make a XMLHttpRequest for the current URL, convert the response into DOM via DOMParser API and extract the og:image tag.

Or you can write site-specific code and try to find an internal variable or element that contains the og:image. It requires some reverse-engineering, and your code would break on site changes.